# refresh firefox from .bat file/ command

Tags: firefox, batch-file

I am attempting to refresh Firefox whenever a bat file is called. I Dont want an extension. I need to know if there is a command that can be used from within a .bat file to reload the current browser or tab.

I know you can use 
`start firefox` as a command but this simply opens a new firefox instance. I need to refresh the current instance.

Comment: Similar solution for linux here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5203419/can-i-force-a-firefox-page-refresh-from-linux-console/7187363#7187363

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was just messing around and came up with this half-working solution that might help a little.  Create a file called something like `refresh.vbs` and paste this in:

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
WshShell.AppActivate("Google Chrome")
WScript.Sleep 500
WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}" 
WScript.Sleep 100
WshShell.SendKeys "{F5}"
```

I could only test it with Chrome.  The script activates Chrome, sends a <kbd>tab</kbd>, and then sends <kbd>F5</kbd> to refresh.  It works when I have Chrome up showing one web page, but not when there are multiple web tabs open (because [AppActivate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wzcddbek(v=VS.85).aspx) activates the Window, but does not give focus to anything).

Maybe it works better with Firefox.  There's probably some way to enumerate the tabs in a browser and activate it in vbs, but I don't know it.

If you spawn the browser within the vbs (see [WshShell.Run](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5fk67ky(v=VS.85).aspx), and the example in the [SendKeys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8c6yea83(v=VS.85).aspx) documentation), you can get the process number and send messages directly to that Window instead of relying on the app title.

You can invoke the .vbs from within a batch file if you need to:

```
@echo off
refresh.vbs
```

Comment: Just to confirm that it works with Firefox 4 too. Just replace "Google Chrome" with "Firefox". Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
On Error Resume Next

Set objExplorer = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

objExplorer.Navigate "http://www.microsoft.com/technet/scriptcenter"   
objExplorer.Visible = 1

Wscript.Sleep 5000

Set objDoc = objExplorer.Document

Do While True

Wscript.Sleep 30000
objDoc.Location.Reload(True)
If Err <> 0 Then
    Wscript.Quit
End If

Loop
```