# Can I force a firefox page refresh from linux console

Tags: linux, firefox, console-application

This is the Linux version of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4160624/refresh-firefox-from-bat-file-command). Does anyone have a method for forcing a page refresh on firefox from the command-line?

Comment: you should edit your first question

Comment: @Krtek - the original question isn't mine, and it is specifically worded for windows (as is the accepted answer)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use xdotool for automation. Install on Ubuntu with

```
sudo aptitude install xdotool
```

Then you can search for windows and send keys or mouse events, see `man xdotool` for the full documentation. I use following script on Ubuntu 10.04 LTS during development:

```
WID=`xdotool search --name "Mozilla Firefox" | head -1`
xdotool windowactivate $WID
xdotool key F5
```

See also the [xdotool project site](http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/)
and [my full blog post](http://www.mobile-web-consulting.de/post/9369063842/shorten-web-development-cycle-refresh-firefox-current).

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15589391/456878), you can also use the xvkbd tool as in the following:

```
$ xvkbd -window Firefox -text "\Cr"
```

Answer (score 2):

The best solution I've found so far..

Install the Firefox Remote Control plugin from:
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/remote-control/

Configure it, enable it (use the icon).

And reload for example with the following command:

```
echo reload | nc -c localhost 32000
```

Comment: Firefox Remote Control no longer works as modern Firefox has limited the ability of plugins to control the browser.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look [here](http://www.mozilla.org/unix/remote.html). 
There is no remote reload-function described. Maybe the site is out-dated and you will find something while browsing through the mentioned *.cpp files. Or you add the function by your-self. The basics to handle such remote-calls seem to be already in Firefox.

Comment: Thanks Maus - I'll take a look at *.cpp

Comment: So maybe it's the solution? ;-)