# How to add a command to refresh firefox use the new setting with command?

Tags: bash, firefox, settings

The firefox setting file located in my pc `/home/.mozilla/firefox/xxxx.default/prefs.js`,when no porxy setting:

```
cat /home/.mozilla/firefox/xxxx.default/prefs.js |grep proxy
user_pref("network.proxy.socks", "127.0.0.1");
user_pref("network.proxy.socks_port", 1080);
user_pref("network.proxy.socks_remote_dns", true);
user_pref("network.proxy.type", 0);
```

Now to set `network.proxy.type`  into `1` with `sed`.

```
sed -i 's/user_pref("network.proxy.type", 0);/user_pref("network.proxy.type", 1);/'  /home/.mozilla/firefox/xxxx.default/prefs.js
```

I found that the firefox can't use proxy when to open webpage,maybe i have to add a new command to make firefox refresh,to use the new proxy setting,how to do then?

Answer (score 0):

Have you had a look at the following guide to make sure all proxy settings are correct?: https://www.itsupportguides.com/knowledge-base/configmgr-sccm/firefox-install-with-proxy-server-settings/

If you are looking for a way to refresh Firefox windows and such the following article has a number of command line tools to achieve this:
[Can I force a firefox page refresh from linux console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5203419/can-i-force-a-firefox-page-refresh-from-linux-console)