# batch-file - batch file to check for open browser script

Tags: batch-file

Right now I have a batch file I created that simple kills a chrome browser and opens up a new one to a particular homepage. I run this on a 5 minute interval with some added software that runs it if there is no activity for 5 minutes. I use this as a timeclock.

I am having some issues with the browser closing and reopening all the time. I figure I can make this script more effiecent by changing a few things.

Instead of closing and open a new browser every 5 minutes I would like to check first if the chome browser is already open and if it is then simple refresh it, otherwise open it.

Here is my current script

```
@echo off

taskkill /f /im chrome.exe

start "chrome" "C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --kiosk "http://www.example.com/sd/clockin/testclockin.php"
```

Answer (score 0):

To check if Chrome is currently running, you can use the `tasklist` command.

```
tasklist | findstr chrome.exe || echo Chrome is not running
```

the code after `||` will only run if an errorlevel is set by the previous command, i.e. if chrome.exe doesn't show up in tasklist. You can use `&&` to execute only if an errorlevel *was not* set.

You can also just check the errorlevel using a simple if statement -

```
if %errorlevel%==1 echo Chrome is running
```

Obviously chrome is closing because you are running the taskkill command. I assume you want to refresh the open page. You may need to look into using VBScript for this. This should help - [refresh firefox from .bat file/ command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4160624/refresh-firefox-from-bat-file-command).